# Sending boolean as request parameter

Tags: java, jsp, controller

In my web application I have a link - "Create New User". From the `jsp` I am sending some request to the server like -

```
<div style="float:right" class="view">
 <a href="/some/url/createUserMVC.do?hasCreatePermission=${user.hasPermission['createUser']}">Create New User</a>
</div>
```

Here `user.hasPermission[]`  is an array of `boolean`. If the current user (that is `user` ) has the permission(that is 'createUser') to create an new user than it returns true.

Now from my controller I am trying to get the value from the request parameter, like -

```
request.getParameter("hasCreatePermission");
```

But the problem is `request.getParameter()` returns a `String`. So how can I get the boolean value from the parameter. There is no overloaded version of `request.getParameter()` method for `boolean`.

Comment: Why don't you use Boolean.parseBoolean()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. Request is always String content. But you can do

```
boolean hasCreatePermission= Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("hasCreatePermission"));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure it's a boolean you can use

```
boolean value = Boolean.valueOf(yourStringValue)
```

Answer (score 4):

All parameters are translated by servelt as String. You need to convert String's value to Boolean.

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("hasCreatePermission"));
```

To avoid manual parsing, you have to use a framework like Spring MVC or Struts.

Answer (score 0):

In servlet it will accept all inputs given by users as string.So, we should parse the input after we got the inputs.

e.g

```
boolean flag = Boolean.parseBoolean(req.getParameter("Flag "));
```

I think this will be useful for you.